# Connect to Postgresql ArcSDE 10.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, arccatalog

I cannot connect to postgresql 9.0.5 with ArcSDE 10.1, using ArcCatalog 10.1 on Win 7 professional 64 bit.

I followed the steps described [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Setting_up_a_geodatabase_in_PostgreSQL/002p00000001000000/), and installed the Pg-Agent from Stack builder. When I execute "Create Enterprise Geodatabase", I set "instance" to "localhost:5432", but I got this error:

```
Cannot connect to database because the database client software failed to load.  Be sure the database client software is installed and configured correctly.
Failed to execute (CreateEnterpriseGeodatabase).
```

I've made sure that the service is running and restarted the whole machine after these installations, but it still gives me the error.

Any help, please?

Comment: The default port for postgresql is 5132. The port is defined in postgresql.conf (if i remember the file name correct).

Comment: BTW, 10.1? Is it some beta version?

Comment: yeah the default port is 5432 , i'm using ArcSDE Windows 1.01 build 129054 final version

Comment: Edit your pg_hba.conf file - you can verify this in pgAdminIII http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/dev/connect-error.html

Comment: there's no errors in Pgadmin or Pg Agent level , but error pop up when i try to make a geodatabase from ArcCatalog

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I may be too late, but in case someone else comes across this forum for the same problem (as I did ;)). This is because you have to install the correct files for your client: 
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Setting_up_a_connection_to_PostgreSQL/002p0000003q000000/.

It took me a while to figure this out as the ESRI online documentation is a labyrinth.

Comment: I just sat in on a presentation at the Esri conference and they said this the most common mistake that users make in trying to set up the connection to a postgres database with ArcSDE.

Comment: Thank you for this post, I have just used this information to download the client from the 'ESRI Customer Care portal' to allow a connection to ArcSDE 9.3.1 from a 10.1 client. Although the versions don't appear to match (8.3 vs 9.0.5) the installation was successful. It can be a little difficult to find the right file, it's under DBMS Support files.